# Angular App with .NET Core Routing Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I created an ASP.NET Core app with Angular using [this guide](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022).
That works as-is, but when I try to add a new controller to the API, it doesn't let me route to that controller action.

I've got the repo here: https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet/tree/main/rardk.web

**Key Information:**

`localhost:4200` is the **Angular** app

`localhost:7042` is the **API**

They are supposedly proxied using proxy.conf.js, but if I comment that file out entirely it still works for the WeatherForecastController.

**Here are the scenarios to illustrate the problem (trying via Postman but also the Angular app calls these endpoints in the app.component.ts):**

https://localhost:4200/weatherforecast -> this works

https://localhost:7042/weatherforecast -> this works

https://localhost:4200/api/now/letterboxd -> this **does not** work

https://localhost:7042/api/now/letterboxd -> this **does** work

**The Question**: if changing the proxy.conf.js does nothing (because I've tried adding the new route to that as well), what is making the weatherforecast endpoint work on port 4200 when nothing else will?

EDIT: adding code snippets to illustrate the problem:

Now Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using rardk.web.BusinessLayer;

namespace rardk.web.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class NowController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILetterboxdBusinessLayer _letterboxdBusinessLayer;

        public NowController(ILetterboxdBusinessLayer letterboxdBusinessLayer)
        {
            _letterboxdBusinessLayer = letterboxdBusinessLayer;
        }

        [HttpGet("letterboxd", Name = "letterboxd")]
        public ActionResult GetLetterboxdFeed()
        {
            _letterboxdBusinessLayer.GetLetterboxdFeed();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Weather Forecast Controller (this works):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace rardk.web.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

proxy.conf.js (doesn't seem to do anything):

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/test"
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7042",
    secure: false
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) we can see that it uses [webpack dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) wich in turn uses [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware).

In the [Options](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options) we can see that is uses [glob matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)):

> globstar: allows ** on its own as a name component to recursively match any number of layers of non-hidden directories.[10] Also supported by the JS libraries and Python's glob.

So as you are using

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

then your context should be `/api/**` to match any nested subfolder (or path in this case) or `/api/*` without nesting

I do not know why using /test as context the WeatherForecast controller is working though

Answer (score 5):

I think you are missing the proxy for the api, the config you set does not proxy the API endpoints

here is what I'm using

```
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'https://localhost:5001';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/_configuration",
      "/.well-known",
      "/Identity",
      "/connect",
      "/ApplyDatabaseMigrations",
      "/_framework",
      "/api",
      "/favicon.ico"
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

by proxying the API endpoints should enable access to this as well

https://localhost:4200/api/now/letterboxd

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Here's my proxy.conf.js


const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api"
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7042",
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

I tried hitting https://localhost:4000/api/now/letterboxd, it doesn't work, but I tried hitting https://localhost:7042/api/now/letterboxd and it works.

Comment: i think you are targetting the wrong url, can you try change to localhost:4000 in the proxy config? suppose to set with the angular endpoint, not api endpoint there

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the **proxy.conf.js** file.

Particularly, the `context` key. From the example you've mentioned, you've proxied `https://localhost:4200/test` to `https://localhost:7042/test`. That's all.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense to me, but why it is that even when it says test, the weatherforecast controller still routes correctly with both ports?

Answer (score 1):

you could try changing the route prefix in the NowController to simply `[controller]`, which means that the full route for the GetLetterboxdFeed action would be `/now/letterboxd`. Then, you could update the proxy.conf.js file to point to `/api` instead of `/test`. This would correctly proxy the API endpoint to https://localhost:7042/api/now/letterboxd, which should work correctly.

Here is an updated version of the NowController with the new route prefix:

```html
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class NowController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILetterboxdBusinessLayer _letterboxdBusinessLayer;

    public NowController(ILetterboxdBusinessLayer letterboxdBusinessLayer)
    {
        _letterboxdBusinessLayer = letterboxdBusinessLayer;
    }

    [HttpGet("letterboxd", Name = "letterboxd")]
    public ActionResult GetLetterboxdFeed()
    {
        _letterboxdBusinessLayer.GetLetterboxdFeed();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

the proxy.conf.js file:

```html
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api"
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7042",
    secure: false
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```